MyBatis handler Issue in my Spring Boot Example for Map Object
I have a problem to implement custom handler for Map through MyBatis in my Spring Boot example.
Here is my request object shown below
@Getter
@Setter
@NoArgsConstructor
@AllArgsConstructor
public class QueryRequest implements Serializable {

    private List<String> years;
    private List<String> months;
    private List<String> region;
    private List<String> office;

}

Here is the response object shown below
@Getter
@Setter
@NoArgsConstructor
@AllArgsConstructor
public class TaskCountResponse implements Serializable {

    private String region;
    private String office;
    private Map<String, Integer> monthlyCounts;

}

Here is the dao shown below
@Repository
public interface QueryTaskDao {

    List<TaskCountResponse> getTaskStatusCounts(QueryRequest queryRequest);
}

Here is the custom handler for Map<String,Integer> shown below
@Slf4j
public class MapTypeHandler extends BaseTypeHandler<Map<String, Integer>> {

    private static final ObjectMapper objectMapper = new ObjectMapper();

    @Override
    public void setNonNullParameter(PreparedStatement ps, int i, Map<String, Integer> parameter, JdbcType jdbcType) throws SQLException {
        try {
            String json = objectMapper.writeValueAsString(parameter);
            log.info("MapTypeHandler | setNonNullParameter | json : " + json);
            ps.setString(i, json);
        } catch (IOException e) {
            throw new SQLException("Error converting Map to JSON", e);
        }
    }

    @Override
    public Map<String, Integer> getNullableResult(ResultSet rs, String columnName) throws SQLException {
        try {
            String json = rs.getString(columnName);
            log.info("MapTypeHandler | getNullableResult(ResultSet rs, String columnName) | json : " + json);
            if (json != null) {
                return objectMapper.readValue(json, new TypeReference<Map<String, Integer>>() {});
            }
            return null;
        } catch (IOException e) {
            throw new SQLException("Error converting JSON to Map", e);
        }
    }

    @Override
    public Map<String, Integer> getNullableResult(ResultSet rs, int columnIndex) throws SQLException {
        try {
            String json = rs.getString(columnIndex);
            log.info("MapTypeHandler | getNullableResult(ResultSet rs, int columnIndex) | json : " + json);
            if (json != null) {
                return objectMapper.readValue(json, new TypeReference<Map<String, Integer>>() {});
            }
            return null;
        } catch (IOException e) {
            throw new SQLException("Error converting JSON to Map", e);
        }
    }

    @Override
    public Map<String, Integer> getNullableResult(CallableStatement cs, int columnIndex) throws SQLException {
        try {
            String json = cs.getString(columnIndex);
            log.info("MapTypeHandler | getNullableResult(CallableStatement cs, int columnIndex) | json : " + json);
            if (json != null) {
                return objectMapper.readValue(json, new TypeReference<Map<String, Integer>>() {});
            }
            return null;
        } catch (IOException e) {
            throw new SQLException("Error converting JSON to Map", e);
        }
    }
}

Here is the XML part of mybatis
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE mapper PUBLIC "-//mybatis.org//DTD Mapper 3.0//EN"
        "http://mybatis.org/dtd/mybatis-3-mapper.dtd">
<mapper namespace="com.example.dao.QueryTaskDao">
    <cache/>

    <!-- Result Map to map query results to TaskStatusCountResponse -->
    <resultMap id="taskStatusCountResultMap" type="com.example.model.TaskStatusCountResponse">
        <result property="region" column="region_name"/>
        <result property="office" column="office_name"/>
        <!-- Handling dynamic columns for monthlyCounts -->
        <result property="monthlyCounts" column="monthlyCounts" javaType="java.util.Map" typeHandler="com.example.utils.MapTypeHandler"/>
    </resultMap>

    <!-- SQL fragment for dynamic filtering -->
    <sql id="queryTaskStatusCondition">
        <where>
            <!-- Filter by years -->
            <if test="years != null and !years.isEmpty()">
                AND SUBSTRING(tt.task_finish_time, 1, 4) IN
                <foreach collection="years" item="year" open="(" close=")" separator=",">
                    #{year}
                </foreach>
            </if>

            <!-- Filter by months -->
            <if test="months != null and !months.isEmpty()">
                AND SUBSTRING(tt.task_finish_time, 6, 2) IN
                <foreach collection="months" item="month" open="(" close=")" separator=",">
                    #{month}
                </foreach>
            </if>

            <!-- Filter by region -->
            <if test="region != null and !region.isEmpty()">
                AND tt.region_name IN
                <foreach collection="region" item="region" open="(" close=")" separator=",">
                    #{region}
                </foreach>
            </if>

            <!-- Filter by office -->
            <if test="office != null and !office.isEmpty()">
                AND tt.office_name IN
                <foreach collection="office" item="office" open="(" close=")" separator=",">
                    #{office}
                </foreach>
            </if>
        </where>
    </sql>

    <!-- Main SQL query to get Task Status Counts -->
    <select id="getTaskStatusCounts" resultMap="taskStatusCountResultMap" parameterType="com.example.model.QueryRequest">
        SELECT
        tt.region_name,
        tt.office_name,

        <!-- Dynamically create counts for each year-month combination -->
        <trim prefix="" suffix="" suffixOverrides=",">
            <foreach collection="years" item="year" separator=",">
                <foreach collection="months" item="month" separator=",">
                    COUNT(CASE WHEN SUBSTRING(tt.task_finish_time, 1, 7) = CONCAT(#{year}, '-', #{month}) THEN 1 END) AS month_${year}_${month}
                </foreach>
            </foreach>
        </trim>

        FROM
        task_list tt
        <include refid="queryTaskStatusCondition"/>
        GROUP BY
        tt.region_name,
        tt.office_name
        ORDER BY
        tt.region_name_en ASC;
    </select>
</mapper>

When I send a request to http://localhost:8048/statistic/getTaskCountsbyTime
{
    "years": ["2022", "2023"],
    "months": ["01", "02", "03"],
    "region": ["A Region", "B Region"],
    "office": ["A Region Office", "B Region Office"]
}

I get this response
[
    {
        "region": "A Region",
        "office": "A Region Office",
        "monthlyCounts": null
    },
    {
        "region": "B Region",
        "office": "B Region Office",
        "monthlyCounts": null
    }
]

The response should look something like this (with actual counts in place of null):
[
    {
        "region": "A Region",
        "office": "A Region Office",
        "monthlyCounts": {
            "month_2022_01": 10,
            "month_2022_02": 15,
            "month_2022_03": 12,
            "month_2023_01": 5,
            "month_2023_02": 7,
            "month_2023_03": 6
        }
    },
    {
        "region": "B Region",
        "office": "B Region Office",
        "monthlyCounts": {
            "month_2022_01": 8,
            "month_2022_02": 14,
            "month_2022_03": 13,
            "month_2023_01": 4,
            "month_2023_02": 6,
            "month_2023_03": 9
        }
    }
]

I get null of monthlyCounts .Where is the problem in xml mapper or mapper type handler?
Can you revise it to fix ?
First try
<select id="getTaskStatusCounts" resultMap="taskStatusCountResultMap" parameterType="com.example.model.QueryRequest">
    SELECT
        tt.region_name AS region,
        tt.office_name AS office,

        CONCAT(
            '{',
            <foreach collection="years" item="year" separator=",">
                <foreach collection="months" item="month" separator=",">
                    CONCAT('"month_${year}_${month}":',
                    COUNT(CASE WHEN SUBSTRING(tt.task_finish_time, 1, 7) = CONCAT(#{year}, '-', #{month}) THEN 1 END))
                </foreach>
            </foreach>,
            '}'
        ) AS monthlyCounts

    FROM
        task_list tt
    <include refid="queryTaskStatusCondition"/>
    GROUP BY
        tt.region_name,
        tt.office_name
    ORDER BY
        tt.region_name_en ASC;
</select>

I also revised it but I get this error message
Cause: java.sql.SQLException: Error converting JSON to Map
; uncategorized SQLException; SQL state [null]; error code [0]; Error converting JSON to Map; nested exception is java.sql.SQLException: Error converting JSON to Map] with root cause
com.fasterxml.jackson.core.JsonParseException: Unexpected character ('"' (code 34)): was expecting comma to separate Object entries
 at [Source: (String)"{"month_2022_01":0"month_2022_02":0"month_2022_03":0"month_2023_01":3"month_2023_02":4"month_2023_03":8}"; line: 1, column: 20]


Here is the answer shown below
1 ) use this query in mapper xml
<select id="getTaskStatusCounts" resultType="map">
  SELECT
    region_name,
    office_name,
    CONCAT(SUBSTRING(task_finish_time, 1, 4), '_', SUBSTRING(task_finish_time, 6, 2)) year_month
  FROM task_list
  <include refid="queryTaskStatusCondition" />
</select>

2 ) Revise MapTypeHandler shown below
public class MapTypeHandler implements TypeHandler<Map<String, Integer>> {
  @Override
  public void setParameter(PreparedStatement ps, int i, Map<String, Integer> parameter, JdbcType jdbcType)
      throws SQLException {
    // not used
  }

  @Override
  public Map<String, Integer> getResult(ResultSet rs, String columnName) throws SQLException {
    return parse(rs.getString(columnName));
  }

  @Override
  public Map<String, Integer> getResult(ResultSet rs, int columnIndex) throws SQLException {
    return parse(rs.getString(columnIndex));
  }

  @Override
  public Map<String, Integer> getResult(CallableStatement cs, int columnIndex) throws SQLException {
    return parse(cs.getString(columnIndex));
  }

  private Map<String, Integer> parse(String str) {
    return Arrays.stream(str.split(",")).map(s -> s.split("="))
        .collect(Collectors.toMap(arr -> arr[0], arr -> Integer.valueOf(arr[1]), (v1, v2) -> v2, TreeMap::new));
  }
}


Type handler deals with a single column, so it is not suitable for your usage.
I can think of a few solutions, but the one using ResultHandler may be the cleanest.
The mapper method would now look as follows.
void getTaskStatusCounts(QueryRequest queryRequest,
    ResultHandler<Map<String, String>> resultHandler);

Here is the new query which is much simpler.
<select id="getTaskStatusCounts" resultType="map">
  SELECT
    region_name,
    office_name,
    CONCAT(SUBSTRING(task_finish_time, 1, 4), '_', SUBSTRING(task_finish_time, 6, 2)) year_month
  FROM task_list
  <include refid="queryTaskStatusCondition" />
</select>

In general, you should avoid a query that has dynamic column count because it is harder to deal with.
And here is the custom result handler.
import java.util.List;
import java.util.Map;
import java.util.TreeMap;
import java.util.Map.Entry;

import org.apache.ibatis.session.ResultContext;
import org.apache.ibatis.session.ResultHandler;

public class TaskCountResponseResultHandler implements ResultHandler<Map<String, String>> {
  private final Map<Entry<String, String>, TaskCountResponse> map = new TreeMap<>(
      (e1, e2) -> {
        int x = e1.getKey().compareTo(e2.getKey());
        return x != 0 ? x : e1.getValue().compareTo(e2.getValue());
      });
  private final List<String> years;
  private final List<String> months;

  public TaskCountResponseResultHandler(List<String> years, List<String> months) {
    super();
    this.years = years;
    this.months = months;
  }

  @Override
  public void handleResult(ResultContext<? extends Map<String, String>> resultContext) {
    // This method is called for each row and
    // this map contains [column label] vs. [column value]
    Map<String, String> row = resultContext.getResultObject();

    Entry<String, String> regionOfficeKey = Map.entry(row.get("REGION_NAME"), row.get("OFFICE_NAME"));
    String monthKey = "month_" + row.get("YEAR_MONTH");

    map.computeIfAbsent(regionOfficeKey, k -> {
      TaskCountResponse v = new TaskCountResponse();
      v.setRegion(k.getKey());
      v.setOffice(k.getValue());
      v.setMonthlyCounts(new TreeMap<>());
      return v;
    }).getMonthlyCounts().merge(monthKey, 1, Integer::sum);
  }

  public List<TaskCountResponse> getResult() {
    return map.values().stream().map(response -> {
      // Puts zero for months with no data
      Map<String, Integer> counts = response.getMonthlyCounts();
      for (String year : years) {
        for (String month : months) {
          counts.putIfAbsent("month_" + year + "_" + month, 0);
        }
      }
      return response;
    }).toList();
  }
}

To execute the query and get the list, your code would look as follows, basically.
List<String> years = List.of("2022", "2023");
List<String> months = List.of("01", "02");

// Prepare parameter
QueryRequest param = new QueryRequest();
param.setYears(years);
param.setMonths(months);

// Create a result handler.
TaskCountResponseResultHandler resultHandler = new TaskCountResponseResultHandler(years, months);
// Execute query.
mapper. getTaskStatusCounts(param, resultHandler);
// Get the list from the result handler.
List<TaskCountResponse> result = resultHandler.getResult();


[EDIT in response to OP's update]
I would not use JSON.
Here is the tricky part of the query.
CONCAT(
<foreach collection="years" item="year" separator=",">
  <foreach collection="months" item="month" separator=",">
    CONCAT('month_',#{year},'_',#{month},'=',
     COUNT(CASE WHEN SUBSTRING(tt.task_finish_time, 1, 7) = CONCAT(#{year}, '-', #{month}) THEN 1 END),
        ',')
  </foreach>
</foreach>
) AS monthlyCounts

MySQL casts the number (i.e. the result of COUNT) implicitly, but some other DBs might need explicit conversion like TO_CHAR.
Unless you are 100% sure there is no malicious String in years or months, you should not use ${} as it could be vulnerable to SQL injection.
The value of monthlyCounts may look like month_2022_01=2,month_2022_02=1,...,.
There is an extra comma at the end, but String#split() in the type handler makes it irrelevant.
And here is the type handler.
import java.sql.CallableStatement;
import java.sql.PreparedStatement;
import java.sql.ResultSet;
import java.sql.SQLException;
import java.util.Arrays;
import java.util.Map;
import java.util.TreeMap;
import java.util.stream.Collectors;

import org.apache.ibatis.type.JdbcType;
import org.apache.ibatis.type.TypeHandler;

public class MapTypeHandler implements TypeHandler<Map<String, Integer>> {
  @Override
  public void setParameter(PreparedStatement ps, int i, Map<String, Integer> parameter, JdbcType jdbcType)
      throws SQLException {
    // not used
  }

  @Override
  public Map<String, Integer> getResult(ResultSet rs, String columnName) throws SQLException {
    return parse(rs.getString(columnName));
  }

  @Override
  public Map<String, Integer> getResult(ResultSet rs, int columnIndex) throws SQLException {
    return parse(rs.getString(columnIndex));
  }

  @Override
  public Map<String, Integer> getResult(CallableStatement cs, int columnIndex) throws SQLException {
    return parse(cs.getString(columnIndex));
  }

  private Map<String, Integer> parse(String str) {
    return Arrays.stream(str.split(",")).map(s -> s.split("="))
        .collect(Collectors.toMap(arr -> arr[0], arr -> Integer.valueOf(arr[1]), (v1, v2) -> v2, TreeMap::new));
  }
}

The demo includes both solutions (it uses HSQLDB).
https://github.com/harawata/mybatis-issues/tree/master/so-79260900

I should only revise MapTypeHandler  or mapper xml file. Can you also produce its answer if you have any idea about it?

As I wrote, type handler deals with a single column, so if you have to use type handler for some reason, you can, for example, concatenate the set of month vs. count into a single string column in the SQL e.g. '202201=10,202202=15,...' AS monthlyCounts, then convert the String into a Map in the type handler. I do not recommend it, but you may be able to figure out how. If you want me to show you the exact code, please let me know which DB version you are using. The SQL would be DB dependent.

I want to share my first try in the post. Can you look through it? I hope you can help me fix the issue.

Updated the answer and the demo.

I forgot to say that I used Mysql for database. Can you update your answer again if you don't mind?

Done. With MySQL, TO_CHAR is unnecessary. That may be the only required change.

I see. I'll try it tomorrow. If there is a problem, I'll inform you about it.

I use your 2nd approach and it helps me fix the issue. Thank you. As I'm new to use mybatis, can I ask some questions in the following times if you don't mind? I also follow your github repo.

Sure. I am watching [mybatis] tag and offering help when I can.
